# How can I pass multiple arraylist of different types to a single recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use a single `RecyclerView.Adapter` to view multiple Arraylists of different object models in multiple fragments.
But I don't know how to do it, is there a way to do it and if possible how can I do it?

I tried to use List object and cast it to the object models I wanted. But I don't know how to use them in onBindViewHolder, I don't know if this is even a proper method.

```
public RItemAdapter(List<?> item,String tag) {
        if(tag.equals("battery"))
        {
             bList = (List<BatteryModel>) item;
        }
        else if(tag.equals("device"))
        {
            dList = (List<DeviceModel>) item;
        }
        else if(tag.equals("network"))
        {
            nList = (List<NetworkModel>) item;
        }
        else if(tag.equals("storage"))
        {
            sList = (List<StorageModel>) item;
        }
        else if(tag.equals("weather"))
        {
            wList = (List<WeatherModel>) item;
    }

    }
```

I want to populate multiple `RecyclerViews` in multiple `Fragments` with a single adapter.

Comment: Create HashMap.... is it expandable recyclerview?

Comment: Can you elaborate?, I want to display data in multiple RecyclerViews in multiple fragments, let me edit that in.

Comment: need to pass a key and from key, you can access hashmap key value

Comment: Please elaborate. What problems are you facing in onBindViewHolder?

Comment: do you want show title for each type?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a base class, other class will inherit from it. You can have a list of the object you want in the inherited classes: each cell will contain a data object that contain a list of other stuff you want to display.
Then in your adapter you have only one list of your base class, and you will set the view type of your object at a position in the getItemViewType method of your adapter. 
In the onBindViewHolder, just switch case on the view type and bind the right ViewHolder to the case.

Here is an example code in Kotlin:

```
class TestAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    companion object {
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_ONE = 0
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_TWO = 1
    }

    private val data = mutableListOf<Data>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder = when (viewType) {
        VIEW_TYPE_ONE -> ViewHolderOne.create(parent)
        VIEW_TYPE_TWO -> ViewHolderTwo.create(parent)
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Viewtype $viewType unhandled")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolderOne -> {
                holder.bind(data[position] as DataOne)
            }
            is ViewHolderTwo -> {
                holder.bind(data[position] as DataTwo)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = when (data[position]) {
        is DataOne -> VIEW_TYPE_ONE
        is DataTwo -> VIEW_TYPE_TWO
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.count()

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = data[position].id

    fun setData(newData: List<MessageUiModel>) {
        data.clear()
        data.addAll(newData)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

sealed class Data

data class DataOne(val list: List<Any>): Data()
data class DataTwo(val list: List<Any>): Data()
```